# Unable to see all textfields on the content view, which is on top of scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have 25 textfields on the contentView, which is on top of scrollview. Due to many textfields i have changed the ViewController simulated size to Freeform and set the height to 1000.

[image]

I have added constraints to scrollview, contentview and textfields.I am able to see every constraint is satisfied

[image]

i have set contentview to equalwidths and equalheights to the View [image]

and when i run it in device i am able to see only 15 textfields in the contentview. I have set the last textfield constraint to BottomSpace of Container.

[image]

I tried setting the BottomSpace of container to Standard Value but facing same issue

[image]

If i remove the bottom constraint of the last textfield then i am able to see all textfields but unable to scroll down. I tried a lot but unable to figure out the issue. As i am new to constraints and auto layout, i am unable to figure it out. If i have 10-15 textfields then everything works fine but if the textfields are more than 15 then i am facing this issue. I guess i am messing some thing with the size of ViewController or with bottom constraint. I am ready to follow any other approach which satisfy my requirement. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIViewController`'s `viewDiDAppear`try to set your `UIScrollView`'s `.contentInset = .zero`

Instead of equalWidths and equalHeights I personally prefer setting the content view's leading, top, trailing and bottom space to the scroll view (set to 0).

Then it is also good to make sure the textfields have explicit heights set.

Answer (score 0):

**How to give constraint in `UIScrollView`**

**ScrollView Constraints**

1. Top, Bottom , leading, Trailing = 0  to super view.

**ContentView Constraints**

1. Top, Bottom , leading, Trailing = 0  to `scrollView`.
2. Equal width to superview of `ScrollView`

**Textfield Constraints**

-For textField1

1. Leading, Trailing , top (constraintvalue as per your requirement) to `ContentView`
2. Height

-For textField2 to textField(n-1)

1. Leading, Trailing , top (constraintvalue as per your requirement) to `Upper textField`
2. Height

-For textField2 to textField(n)

1. Leading, Trailing , top (constraintvalue as per your requirement) to `Upper textField`
2. Height
3. Bottom to `ContentView`

**Important:**

As `UIScrollView` height is depends on the `contentView` height,as we give the constraints `contentView` w.r.t. to `UIScrollView`. The height of `contentView`is calculated by its inner content as constraints of each component  have height and first component have top constraint to `contentView` and last view have bottom constraint to `contentView`.

**NOTE :**
Never give static height to `UIScrollView` and `contentView`.